# How to get multiple selected values from dropdown?

Tags: jquery

I have implemented the tag control in Stack OVerflow using the Harvest HQ Chosen plugin taken from github in my local project.

But I have one question, I believe this control can only be used with dropdowns, if thats the case, How can I get list of selected values.. Say suppose I have items as "Quoted", "Non_Quoted", "Yet to Quote", "Removed From Quoting" and I have selected the "Quoted" and "Yet to Quote" options, if I say dropdown.selectedvalue, it is giving me the "YetToQuote" alone as the value.

But I need all the values that are selected, in the above example bothe Quoted and Yet To Quote.

How can I achieve this. Please help me..

Thanks and appreciate your help.

Can I implement the same for textbox instead of dropdown..with textbox having autocomplete feature of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

`$("option:selected", dropdown)` would find all the selected options I believe. I've not tested it though.

Answer (score 0):

The `val()` method on jQuery will do the trick for you. Quoting from http://api.jquery.com/val/:

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form
>   elements. In the case of  elements, the
>   .val() method returns an array containing each selected option.